# Filtering datatables using daterangepicker

Tags: jquery, asp.net, datatables-1.10, daterangepicker, adminlte

I am using AdminLTE templete for my project with same tables format.

If I add daterangepicker to my html, how can I filter my datatables?

This is my code:

```
<section class="content">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="box">
                <div class="box-header">
                    <h3 class="box-title">Access Log View</h3>
                </div>

                <!-- /.box-header -->
                <div class="box-body">
                    <div class=" col-xs-3">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <div class="input-group-addon">
                                    <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
                                </div>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control pull-left" id="findDate">
                            </div>
                            <!-- /.input group -->
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <table id="example2" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Date</th>
                                <th>Name</th>
                                <th>User</th>
                                <th>Log Type</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>24/03/2018</td>
                                <td>UserOne</td>
                                <td>reksa@gmail.com</td>
                                <td>Login</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>23/03/2018</td>
                                <td>UserOne</td>
                                <td>reksa@gmail.com</td>
                                <td>Login</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>22/03/2018</td>
                                <td>UserOne</td>
                                <td>reksa@gmail.com</td>
                                <td>Login</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>21/03/2018</td>
                                <td>UserOne</td>
                                <td>reksa@gmail.com</td>
                                <td>Login</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>20/03/2018</td>
                                <td>UserOne</td>
                                <td>reksa@gmail.com</td>
                                <td>Login</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>24/03/2018</td>
                                <td>UserOne</td>
                                <td>reksa@gmail.com</td>
                                <td>Login</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>24/03/2018</td>
                                <td>UserOne</td>
                                <td>reksa@gmail.com</td>
                                <td>Login</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>24/03/2018</td>
                                <td>UserOne</td>
                                <td>reksa@gmail.com</td>
                                <td>Login</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>24/03/2018</td>
                                <td>UserOne</td>
                                <td>reksa@gmail.com</td>
                                <td>Login</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>24/03/2018</td>
                                <td>UserOne</td>
                                <td>reksa@gmail.com</td>
                                <td>Login</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>24/03/2018</td>
                                <td>UserOne</td>
                                <td>reksa@gmail.com</td>
                                <td>Login</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>24/03/2018</td>
                                <td>UserOne</td>
                                <td>reksa@gmail.com</td>
                                <td>Login</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <!-- /.box-body -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.box -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.col -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.row -->
</section>
<!-- /.content -->
<!-- /.box -->
@section Scripts {
<script>

    $(function () {
        $('#example2').DataTable({
            'paging': true,
            'lengthChange': false,
            'searching': true,
            'ordering': false,
            'info': true,
            'autoWidth': false
        })
    });

    //Date range picker
    $('#findDate').daterangepicker();

</script>
}
```

I am still confused with get data for my daterangepicker and how to filter my datatables.

Because data tables already have search pagging and another extension for tables, how do I filter using daterangepicker with my datatables, and sort my data tables according to datepicker selected.

Comment: you are using http://www.daterangepicker.com/  or https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/?

Comment: @DPS im using daterangepicker.com

Comment: you are apply a filter for static data or dynamic?

Comment: @SanyamiVaidya dynamic data

Answer (score 0):

You can try this for server side searching,

**HTML:**

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control pull-left" id="findDate">
 <button type="button" id="btnFilter" class="btn btn-default">Search</button>
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  bindGrid('');
        $("#btnFilter").click(function () {

                var parameters = $('#findDate').val();
                bindGrid(parameters);


        });
});
function bindGrid(parameters) {  
      $('#example2').DataTable({
        "sAjaxSource": "URL",
        "fnServerParams": function (aoData) {
            aoData.push({ "name": "DateRange", "value": parameters });
            perm = aoData;
        },
            'paging': true,
            'lengthChange': false,
            'searching': true,
            'ordering': false,
            'info': true,
            'autoWidth': false
        })
    });
}
```

In `DateRange`, you get fromdate-todate,
after that, you can split DateRange and apply between query in your database.